# Drag&Drop cannot work when column is sorted in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The re-arrangement of rows work as intended initially, but if a column is sorted drag & drop of rows does not work.

Further, if I cancel column sorting in datagrid, drag and drop feature works fine.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCollection : ObservableCollection<Product>
{
    public ProductCollection()
    {
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 111, ProductName = "Books", ProductPrice = "500$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 222, ProductName = "Cameras", ProductPrice = "600$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 333, ProductName = "Cell Phones", ProductPrice = "700$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 444, ProductName = "Clothing", ProductPrice = "800$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 555, ProductName = "Shoes", ProductPrice = "900$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 666, ProductName = "Gift Cards", ProductPrice = "500$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 777, ProductName = "Crafts", ProductPrice = "400$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 888, ProductName = "Computers", ProductPrice = "430$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 999, ProductName = "Coins", ProductPrice = "460$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 332, ProductName = "Cars", ProductPrice = "4600$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 564, ProductName = "Boats", ProductPrice = "3260$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 346, ProductName = "Dolls", ProductPrice = "120$" });
        Add(new Product() { ProductId = 677, ProductName = "Gift Cards", ProductPrice = "960$" });

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfRowDragDropSample"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WpfRowDragDropSample.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ProductCollection x:Key="ProductList"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductList}}">
        <DataGrid d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Margin="0,28,0,0" Name="productsDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" ColumnWidth="*" AllowDrop="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Header="ProductId"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Header="ProductName"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductPrice}" Header="ProductPrice"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="DataGrid Row Drag And Drop Sample" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,1,0,0" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="268" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

public delegate Point GetPosition(IInputElement element);
int rowIndex = -1;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    productsDataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(productsDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
    productsDataGrid.Drop += new DragEventHandler(productsDataGrid_Drop);
}

void productsDataGrid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (rowIndex < 0)
        return;
    int index = this.GetCurrentRowIndex(e.GetPosition);           
    if (index < 0)
        return;
    if (index == rowIndex)
        return;           
    if (index == productsDataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This row-index cannot be drop");
        return;
    }
    ProductCollection productCollection = Resources["ProductList"] as ProductCollection;
    Product changedProduct = productCollection[rowIndex];
    productCollection.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
    productCollection.Insert(index, changedProduct);
}

void productsDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rowIndex = GetCurrentRowIndex(e.GetPosition);
    if (rowIndex < 0)
        return;
    productsDataGrid.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
    Product selectedEmp = productsDataGrid.Items[rowIndex] as Product;
    if (selectedEmp == null)
        return;
    DragDropEffects dragdropeffects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    if (DragDrop.DoDragDrop(productsDataGrid, selectedEmp, dragdropeffects)
                        != DragDropEffects.None)
    {               
        productsDataGrid.SelectedItem = selectedEmp;
    }
}

private bool GetMouseTargetRow(Visual theTarget, GetPosition position)
{
    Rect rect = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(theTarget);
    Point point = position((IInputElement)theTarget);
    return rect.Contains(point);           
}

private DataGridRow GetRowItem(int index)
{
    if (productsDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.Status
            != GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        return null;
    return productsDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)
                                                    as DataGridRow;
}

private int GetCurrentRowIndex(GetPosition pos)
{
    int curIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < productsDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow itm = GetRowItem(i);
        if (GetMouseTargetRow(itm, pos))
        {
            curIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return curIndex;
}
```

Image 1:
[Now select a row to drop on place of other row like I select computers product row to put on the top of the grid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7c41.jpg)

Image 2:
[Drag and drop selected row to other place.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKSiZ.jpg)

I would like drag & drop has higher priority than column sorting so both can work simultaneously.

Comment: To sort properly by currency, the `ProductPrice` property must be of type `decimal`. Otherwise you get wrong sorting. Numeric strings are sorted lexical, which means "111" comes before "2", which is wrong. When sorted numeric, "111" comes after "2".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the SortIndex class. I have updated the answer in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sort doesn't work because you are trying to modify the underlying collection while the `DataGrid` is actively sorting the `CollectionView` (Microsoft Docs: [Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0#collection-views)).

You basically have introduced a second sort criteria. The first is the column's sort criteria (e.g., numeric sort). After this primary sort criteria you want to sort by index (essentially you are changing the index of a dragged row).
This means, instead of moving items around you must project your criteria into a sort description. In other words, if you don't merge those two sorts the column sort will always override your source collection modifications. You must "move" items by sorting them.

First of all, you must work on collections view only. When the `DataGrid` sorts, it sorts the `ICollectionView` of the underlying collection. This means, if you are looking for an index of the sorted (or filtered) `DataGrid` (or `ItemsControl` in general), you *must* retrieve this index from the collection view, for example:

```cs
ItemsControl.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

And if you are looking for an item of the sorted/filtered `ItemsControl`:

```cs
ItemsControl.Items.GetItemAt(itemIndex);
```

Otherwise what you see is not what you get. The indices of a sorted `CollectionView` and the underlying unsorted collection like `ProductCollection` are not identical.
When debugging your original code you should see that you are moving the item in the underlying `ProductCollection`. But still you see the items not being arranged accordingly in the `DataGrid`.
This is because the `DataGrid` doesn't care how the underlying `ProductCollection` is ordered as long there is a sort or filter applied to the `CollectionView` (when clicking a `DataGrid` column the `DataGrid` implicitly assigns a `SortDescription` to the `CollectionView` it binds to).

In your special case, where you want to apply your custom sort criteria *after* the primary sort criteria of the column was applied, you can simplify the sorting: to improve performance you don't have to execute the column sorting every time the user drags a row.
It is sufficient if you track the index of the items in the collection view after the initial column sort. In other words, after the initial column sort (e.g. by property name) you save a snapshot of the current indices. Because we are now only interested in the dragged row's index relative to the *displayed* view in the `DataGrid`. We change the index of the sorted `CollectionView` and not of the underlying `ProductCollection` collection.

To do so we apply our custom sort algorithm once a drop occurred. We can assign a custom sort algorithm by assigning an `IComparer` to the `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` property.

All we do is to change the index of the dropped item and the index of the other items.
But because we are working on the `ICollectionView` we can't really move items. Additionally we have to maintain the original indices that were the result of the initial column sort.
To get around this we have to abstract away the item index after a previous column sort, so that we can use them as our sort criteria. We could add a new property to the row data model. A cleaner solution would be to create a table to track and manipulate those abstracted row indices. Table structures like `Dictionary<K,V>` are perfect for fast lookup, what is needed here.

To achieve this, the following example has introduced a `SortedIndex` type. It is a linked index object that is able to insert other `SortIndex` nodes and automatically adjust the index of the following nodes.
It basically behaves like a doubly linked list. `SortIndex` will simplify the maintenance of the collection indices. Because we don't have to find the insertion item in the collection in order to virtually move all the following items, we also improve the performance.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Window>  
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" 
            Sorting="OnProductsDataGridSorting"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowDrop="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Header="ProductId" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Header="ProductName" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductPrice}" Header="ProductPrice" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainPage : Window
{
  public ProductCollection ProductList { get; }
  private bool IsSortIndexingPending { get; set; }
  private Dictionary<Product, SortIndex> ProductSortPriorityTable { get; }
  public delegate Point GetPosition(IInputElement element);
  int rowIndex = -1;

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ProductList = new ProductCollection();
    this.ProductSortPriorityTable = new Dictionary<Product, SortIndex>();
    this.IsSortIndexingPending = true;

    productsDataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(productsDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
    productsDataGrid.Drop += new DragEventHandler(productsDataGrid_Drop);
  }

  private void OnProductsDataGridSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
  {
    this.CurrentColumnSortComparer = ((CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ProductList)).Comparer;
    this.ProductSortPriorityTable.Clear();
    this.IsSortIndexingPending = true;
  }

  void productsDataGrid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  {
    /*** Your existing code (unchanged) ***/
    
    if (this.rowIndex < 0)
      return;
    int index = GetCurrentRowIndex(e.GetPosition);
    if (index < 0)
      return;
    if (index == this.rowIndex)
      return;
    if (index == this.productsDataGrid.Items.Count - 1)
    {
      _ = MessageBox.Show("This row-index cannot be drop");
      return;
    }

    /*** New code ***/

    var collectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ProductList);
    IndexCurrentSortedProductListView(CollectionView collectionView);

    var droppedProductItem = (Product)collectionView.GetItemAt(this.rowIndex);
    SortIndex droppedProductItemSortIndex = this.ProductSortPriorityTable[droppedProductItem];
    var dropTargetProductItem = (Product)collectionView.GetItemAt(index);
    SortIndex dropTargetProductItemSortIndex = this.ProductSortPriorityTable[dropTargetProductItem];

    // Virtually move the dropped row item. 
    // Because the CollectionView does not support moving items, 
    // we have to rearrange the collection view by applying a new sort.
    // This index based sort uses the pre-sorted indices 
    // and not the original indices from the underlying ProductList collection.
    dropTargetProductItemSortIndex.InsertNext(droppedProductItemSortIndex);

    // Finally sort by new index based on the pre-sorted collection view
    collectionView.CustomSort = Comparer<Product>.Create((product1, product2) =>
    {
      int rowItemPriority1 = this.ProductSortPriorityTable[product1].Index;
      int rowItemPriority2 = this.ProductSortPriorityTable[product2].Index;
      return rowItemPriority1.CompareTo(rowItemPriority2);
    });
  }

  private void IndexCurrentSortedProductListView(CollectionView collectionView)
  {
    if (this.IsSortIndexingPending)
    {
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.ProductList.Count; rowIndex++)
      {
        SortIndex sortIndex;
        if (rowIndex > 0)
        {
          int previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
          var previousRowItem = (Product)collectionView.GetItemAt(previousRowIndex);
          SortIndex previousSortIndex = this.ProductSortPriorityTable[previousRowItem];
          sortIndex = new SortIndex(rowIndex, previousSortIndex, null);
          previousSortIndex.SetNext(sortIndex);
        }
        else
        {
          sortIndex = new SortIndex(rowIndex);
        }

        var rowItem = (Product)collectionView.GetItemAt(rowIndex);
        this.ProductSortPriorityTable.Add(rowItem, sortIndex);
      }

      this.IsSortIndexingPending = false;
    }
  }

  void productsDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    /*** Nothing has changed here ***/
  }

  private bool GetMouseTargetRow(Visual theTarget, GetPosition position)
  {   
    /*** Nothing has changed here ***/
  }

  private DataGridRow GetRowItem(int index)
  {
    /*** Nothing has changed here ***/
  }

  private int GetCurrentRowIndex(GetPosition pos)
  {    
    /*** Nothing has changed here ***/
  }
}
```

**SortIndex.cs**

```
internal class SortIndex
{
  public SortIndex(int index) : this(index, null, null)
  {
  }

  public SortIndex(int index, SortIndex? previous, SortIndex? next)
  {
    this.Index = index;
    this.Previous = previous;
    this.Next = next;
  }

  public int Index { get; private set; }
  public SortIndex? Previous { get; private set; }
  public SortIndex? Next { get; private set; }
  public bool HasNext => this.Next is not null;
  public bool HasPrevious => this.Previous is not null;

  public void InsertNext(SortIndex nextSortIndex)
  {
    if (nextSortIndex.HasPrevious)
    {
      nextSortIndex.Previous.Next = nextSortIndex.Next;
    }

    if (nextSortIndex.HasNext)
    {
      nextSortIndex.Next.Previous = nextSortIndex.Previous;
    }

    nextSortIndex.Previous = this;
    nextSortIndex.Next = this.Next;
    if (this.HasNext)
    {
      this.Next.Previous = nextSortIndex;
    }

    this.Next = nextSortIndex;
    SetNextIndex(this.Index + 1);
  }

  public void SetNext(SortIndex nextSortIndex)
  {
    this.Next = nextSortIndex;
    nextSortIndex.Previous = this;
    SetNextIndex(this.Index + 1);
  }

  public void SetPrevious(SortIndex previousSortIndex)
  {
    this.Previous = previousSortIndex;
    previousSortIndex.Next = this;
    SetIndex(previousSortIndex.Index + 1);
  }

  public void Increment()
  {
    this.Index++;
    this.Next?.Increment();
  }

  public void SetIndex(int index)
  {
    this.Index = index;
    SetNextIndex(this.Index + 1);
  }

  private void SetNextIndex(int nextIndex) => this.Next?.SetIndex(nextIndex);
}
```

Comment: Is CustomSort is an extension method for CollectionView class and needs to be implemented separately? Please share the code for SortIndex

Comment: I have already added the SortIndex implementation. about 3hrs ago. Even gave you a note. `CustomSort` is a property of the `ListCollectionView`. You must cast `CollectionView` to `ListCollectionView`(like I did in the example). See *MainPage.xaml.cs*, the very first line in the _/*** New code ***/_ section. Feel free to come back if you need more help.

Comment: ProductSortPriorityTable seems to be updated with the data once the column header is clicked as it executes the sort event and the DataGrid appears to be updated. However, drag and drop display the correct "droppedProductItem" and "dropTargetPointItem" but it updates the DataGrid once and then remains stuck. Once again the column header is clicked it allows to drag and drop only one time but not at the intended location.

Comment: You must add `this.IsSortIndexingPending = true;` to the constructor of `MainPage`. I have updated the example accordingly.

Comment: All we need to is to switch the DataGrid rows every time user drag one row to another and when the column header is clicked it sort the column in asscending and descending order, these are the only two requirements; not sure why do we need to compare the two products? Is it possible to simply switch the Source row with Target row in the collectionView.CustomSort method?

Comment: The comparison is the sort. Again, we can't simply move items around because there is a sort active - the column sort. This is important to understand. If there is no sort active then moving would be no problem (although moving items in a collection results in worse performance then virtually moving them by sorting). What we are essentially doing is to merge the reordering introduced by the drag&drop into the active column sort. That's why we sort (compare) instead of literally moving items in the underlying collection.

Comment: In other words, you were originally already  trying to move items in the underlying collection - which doesn't work obviously. That collided with the active sort. When you modify the collection the collection view is immediately sorted, which make it appear that the item wasn't moved. Moving an item "physically" changes the index in the *collection*. BUT the *collection view* does not care about this index. It maintains it's own indexing to realize sorting and filtering.

Comment: When you see data in a ListBox or DataGrid you are always looking at the *collection view* and not *collection*. If there is no sort or filter applied, then both *collection view* and *collection* match. The second line of my answer provides a link that explains it. If you understand the relationship between *collection view* and the underlying *collection* than you understand that moving an item "physically" has no impact on the sorted/filtered view as the view will order the items based on the sort/filter rule.

Comment: In order to modify the active sort order, we run or own sort rules after the column sort. We can only *sort* the view in order to change the index in the view - when the view maintains its own index due to an active sort/filter rule, which is the case in your scenario (column sort is active). We can't move items. Moving items means always "physically" moving them in the underlying collection.